# Can I use Graphics object in any other event than Paint event?

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I have a WinForm with a docked Panel.
I overrode the Panel’s Paint event. 
I have a line that sets up _graphics object:

```
private Graphics _graphics;
```

In the override I initialize _graphics object:

```
private void GridPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    _graphics = e.Graphics;

    <snip>
    …
    </snip>
}
```

Here comes the stupid part, Can I use this _graphics object in any other event like MouseMove?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759646/how-to-manually-get-instance-of-graphics-object-in-winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759646/how-to-manually-get-instance-of-graphics-object-in-winforms)

Comment: You can (and for the sake of short code portions __should__) pass out the `e.Graphics` object __from__ the `Paint` event to helper functions. Do __not__ try to __cache__ it (and also do not use `CreateGraphics`) or else __terrible__ things will happen ! - So the answer is __NO__ you should not do that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what do you mean by "use".

`Graphics` is disposable. After repainting, control disposes `Graphics` instance, that was passed into `Paint` event handler. From that point, disposed object is useless. But caching a reference to that instance is absolutely legal.

Comment: In the Paint event I draw a grid in the Panel using a gray pen. In the MouseMove I want to repaint the grid square the mouse pointer is currently in with a red pen.

Comment: @Randy: you don't need to remember graphics. Instead, remember square parameters to repaint and call `Invalidate`.

Comment: Use the MouseMove event only to identify the cell you want to change and to force a redraw of the control if that cell changed. Then in the Paint handler you add your custom drawing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use graphics object of your control using [`CreateGraphics`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.creategraphics(v=vs.110).aspx) method where you want, **but** when the control refreshes, your painting will disappear.

**So** it's better to draw what you need, in [`Paint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.110).aspx) event based on some logic, then each time the control refreshes, your paint logic will apply and the drawing will show on your control.

**For example** when you want to draw a rectangle in your `MouseMove` event, its enough to store the rectangle in a class member variable, and call `yourControl.Invalidate();` and then use the rectangle in the `Paint` event handler and draw it. [`Invalidate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a(v=vs.110).aspx) makes the control redraw, so your painting logic will run.

Comment: It's very good to post a comment about the reason of down vote and let me know what's wrong with the answer.

Comment: Someone probebly saw `CreateGraphics` and automatically downvoted.

Comment: @TaW and how does `CreateGraphics` deserve a down vote without reading the rest of the answer. :-/

Comment: Didn't say it does, just think that's a plausible explanation. Some folks look for any reason to downvote..

Comment: @TaW Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: @TaW  I think if SO shows a log for votes, we will see unreasonable votes less.

Comment: Haha! If you want to see a real number downvotes you could suggest this on Meta. You will get -100 in under one hour, I bet.. (The reasoning is: The voting should happen uninhibited to work best. The same reason for 1 dv costing only one rep point)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Graphics outside of your `Paint/PaintBackground` events, but you shouldn't need to, nor is it advised.

My guess is (given that you referenced `MouseMove`) that you want some painting to occur when particular events occur on the control; there are a couple of solutions to this:

- Subclassing (greater control over your component, control reuse etc)
- Registering event handlers (good for quick and dirty implementation)

**Example 1 - registering event handlers**

```
private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // forces paint event to fire for entire control surface    
    panel1.Refresh();
}

private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.....;
}
```

**Example 2 - subclassing**

```
class CustomControl : Control
{
    public CustomControl()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintInWmPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        UpdateStyles();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        Refresh();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        e.Graphics...;
    }
}
```

**Notes**

1. Once `OnPaint/Paint` has been called, e.Graphics will be disposed, therefore, setting a global reference to that object will be useless since it will be `null` once your Paint event has completed.
2. You can use `CreateGraphics()` if you absolutely need `Graphics` outside of your `Paint/PaintBackground` methods/events, but this isn't advised.
3. `Paint/PaintBackground` fall naturally into the WinForms event/rendering pipeline, so you should ideally override these and use them appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

If you want repaint panel on MouseMove event, call the `Invalidate()` method and do the draw logic on `Paint` event.

The `Invalidate()` method marks the panel "dirty" and the painting will be caused from winforms message-loop.